# MySQL query: Date > Date not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

Hi there please help me if you can. Here is my senario:

I have a MySQL database with a column that holds a date in the form of a varchar. The format of the date is the following 29/05/2014 (i.e. d/m/Y).

I'm trying to compare the value of this column with todays date and return any rows where the date is earlier than todays date.

**I'm using a php variable to store todays as follows:**

```
$date = date("d/m/Y");
```

**Here is my SQL query:**

```
SELECT * FROM patients WHERE last_seen < '$date'
```

**What gets returned**

So what is returned is very unusual (to me). All records where the last_seen "day" is less than todays "day". It seems to be overlooking the month and year. So in other words if I last_seen = "30/05/2014" and todays date is "29/05/2014" this record is still returned.

Does anyone have any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you storing the date in a varchar field?

Comment: So you're trying to do an inequality comparison on two strings?

Comment: Never store dates in varchars, SQL has a date/datetime type for this.

Comment: If you store something as a text string, it's going to compare as a text string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really, really shouldn't store dates in a varchar field - use date or datetime or timestamp data type.

That said, sometimes you don't have control over the database and you have to deal with somebody else's bad design decision.  In this case, to compare dates, convert the varchar strings to dates and compare them that way.  So, in your case, you can have something like this:

```
$date = date("d/m/Y");
```

and then

```
SELECT * FROM patients WHERE str_to_date('last_seen', '%d/%m/%Y') < str_to_date('$date', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

or simpler

```
SELECT * FROM patients WHERE date(last_seen) < current_date
```

This way you are actually comparing dates and not strings containing dates.  Naturally, this assumes that all dates are stored in the same format.

**EDIT:** I just tested the last option - and, apparently, `date('30/05/2014')` returns `NULL` on my system (mysql 5.5 on linux), hence I suggest the best way is

```
SELECT * FROM patients WHERE str_to_date('last_seen', '%d/%m/%Y') < current_date
```

Comment: Much appreciated. Hands up, it was my bad design, i'm still learning. As the database was only populated with a few test records I was able to convert the column to datetime and it works a treat. What is the best way to insert the current date for this column? Is it CURDATE() or CURRENT_DATE?

Comment: @user711909 either way is fine - you'll get the same results - I believe, internally one calls the other.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your date as `DATE` or `DATETIME` in your database.

Then you can use:

`SELECT * FROM patients WHERE DATE(last_seen) < CURRENT_DATE`